# How to use vimgrep on several file extensions

Tags: vim

So I'm working on a project with several resources: XML, javascript, QML, images, 3D scenes.
I often want to search for patterns inside my project. Using vimgrep /mypattern/j ** is quite long, especially since it searches inside binary files.
I could use

```
:vimgrep /mypattern/j *.xml
:vimgrepadd /mypattern/j *.js
```

But I would prefer to do it in one command.

Another way to look at it: how to prevent vimgrep to search inside binary files?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can pass multiple file globs to `:vimgrep`:

```
:vimgrep /mypattern/j *.xml *.js
```

To exclude certain files, you can configure the `'wildignore'` option to exclude them, e.g.

```
:set wildignore=*.dll,*.exe
```

Comment: +1 Again a "omg" moment... The time I could have saved already knowing this sooner. Thx Ingo.

Comment: +1 for the `wildignore` thing. Note that vim globs are a lot more powerful, e.g. `**/*.xml **/*.js` or `**/config/*.xml src/**/*.js` and there's [_even_ Upward Searching](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#file-searching)

Comment: @sehe: Well, I submitted that patch that made `:vimgrep` use it :-) It's in version 7.3.570.

Comment: Oh nice, I'm sure you thought of `lvimgrep` as well (or it just shares the code)

Comment: @sehe, @Ingo,  Is there any option in vim (`vimgrep`), to prevent it from searching in all binary files?

Comment: or do I have to add each binary filetype to wildignore, for it to ignore that type of file while searching?

Comment: @alpha_989 Seeing that [you wrote this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15244/5359) I'm not going to spend a lot of time: I don't think it exists :)

Comment: I kind of found a way.. but it uses a combination of vimgrep, find and grep: `:vim pattern \`find . \( -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*path.*' \) -exec grep -lI '.*' {} \;\``

Comment: @sehe and Ingot.. would love your thoughts on https://stackoverflow.com/a/50652158/4752883.. and if this can be improved

Comment: I tested this on vim 8.1 and it shows error of `Cannot open file "*.h"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `vim`, `find` and `grep` to perform very complicated searches. Here's an example:

`` :vim /pattern/g `find ~ \( -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*js' -exec grep -lI '.*' {} \;` ``

### Explanation of the commands:

`find ~ \( -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*js'`

This enables you to define a starting directory to start your search, and then define a pattern on the filenames or dates that you want to search with.

`-type f`: defines that you should only look for files

`-regextype posix-extended -regex '.*js'`: defines that you should search for file names that match the pattern `.*js`.

`-exec grep -lI '.*' {} \;`: this executes the grep command. This is needed because the `find` command doesn't have the ability to distinguish between binary and text files because it doesn't look inside files. `grep` does look inside files. The `.*` tells `grep` that any combination of characters are a match.

`-lI`: This indicates to `grep` to look at the first few bits and determine if the file is binary or not. If it is a binary file, it will just keep processing as if there is not match. `-l` here just prints out the name of the file name.

The entire command `find ~ \( -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*' -exec grep -lI '.*' {} \;` is passed as an `argslist` to vim (http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/).

---

### Advantage of this method:

1. You don't have to define `wildignore` very careful to include all types of binary files
2. You can keep the command in the saved commands, which is saved in `.viminfo`. By using `q:` you can bring up the previously entered `ex` mode commands and then search within the buffer to find this particular command and just change the necessary fields
3. While you can do the same in the terminal, the advantage is that you have a quickfix list which is populated and you can just within the quickfix list with `:cn`
4. While you are piping the command through multiple programs, the amount of actual execution time should be much lower, vim will not search through a lot of binary files which it will by default unless each and every binary file-type is listed.
5. You don't have to maintain a large list of binary files to ignore in `wildignore`

You should still fill out `wildignore` carefully as @Ingo-karat pointed out because `wildignore` is used by a lot of program.

---

### How can this be improved further

Instead of `vimgrep`, perhaps you can directly use `gr` and you may be able to directly provide the `-lI` arguments to it, through `greprg`. However, I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: As this filters both by file extension and binary type, I think it is more than the OP asked for. If I were to use such, I would define a custom `:command` with arguments for it, not rely on the command history for recall.

Comment: Ah ook. Thanks for the feedback. didn't know about `:command`. Will look into it..

Comment: Hey, thanks for contributing. Your idea is very interesting, but it lacks something very important to me: working indifferently in Windows or any Unix out of the box. Using find and grep in Vim, while very efficient, doesn't work everywhere.

Comment: You are right.. Actually I have to develop for Windows as well.. but I have given up on Windows for determining the actual development environment (I use Windows VMs for the testing part).. Most new plugins and features come out on Unix-like systems first.. and is much more stable in them. While my perspective may be limited.. I have found it to be much better environment to use Unix-like working environment.. even if I am developing for windows..

Comment: Have you tried `cygwin`, if you can't actually use a ubuntu VM?